# Linkedin Creative Search API - Paging not working properly

Tags: linkedin-api

We noticed that in creative search API, we used to get total count of records in total field of paging section as shown below. But we observed that, recently it's showing count value if total number of records are more than count.
Example : If our creative search URL with start = 0 and count = 100 gives total 350 records in response, then we used to get 350 as total value in paging section and 100 records in elements section as count is 100. But now we observed that it's not giving 350 value in paging section, it gives 100 which is same as count value when number of total records are more than count value. This is happening for all versions (we tried from Nov 2022 till March 2023).

Sample URL : https://api.linkedin.com/rest/creatives?accounts=List($account)&q=criteria&start=0&count=100
Sample Response :
{
"paging": {
"start": 0,
"count": 100,
"links": [{
"type": "application/json",
"rel": "next",
"href": "/rest/creatives?q=criteria&start=0&count=100&accounts=List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A507513780)"
}
],
**"total":** 100
},
"elements": [{
…}]

Does anyone know is this recent change ?
How this can be fixed if we want to get total number of records value ?